# Is it possible to terminate a loop, if items within a given iterable (list/tuple) isn't updated after looping for given x times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```py
from wmi import WMI
from os import getpid
pid = getpid()
Win32_Process = WMI().Win32_Process()

while True:
    for process in Win32_Process:
        if process.ProcessID == pid:
            pid = process.ParentProcessId
            print(process.name)
```

I am trying to iterate through a list of running processes on my system to generate a traceback of child/parent processes chain i.e:

```
python.exe < powershell.exe < Code.exe < Code.exe < Code.exe < explorer.exe
```

My problem is after looping for sometime the traceback finishes or doesn't return anything & it keeps on looping, basically I have no idea how to terminate the parent `while` loop.

I even tried to compare the initial and final length of a traceback tuple, that seemed to work but limited the range of the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
while True:
    for process in Win32_Process:
```

Simply get rid of the `while` loop, as the `for` loop suffices.

---

That said, the order of processes matters,
so you might want to sort them by `.ProcessID`
before you start looping over them.

Or throw them all into a `dict` and iterate over that.
Or consider using one of the various graph packages,
such as https://pypi.org/project/networkx ,
to help you navigate through the parent-child
relationships of the process tree, and display them.